# How To Remove Black Shadows On ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04

Can somebody help me please :( ... i have an problem after installation 
ubuntu system 

I tried to install Ubuntu 16.04, and the installation process went fine. So when I tried to start Ubuntu for many times,Unfortunately i didn't know whats happen ,every thing was like the pictures below.
this some screenshots : 
[image: screenhot1]

[image: screenhot2]

and i cann't use terminal , because it look fully covered with black one and when i typing , nothing appear :

my version of system is 16.04LTS 
 i hope to solve it :( ,

Comment: Ambiance (default) !!

Comment: What theme are you using?

Comment: i am using Ambiance (default) !!

Answer (score 0):

Install CCSM:

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

search for it in dash, run, and change the following settings:

- Window decoration -> Active Shadow -> Radius, set it to 0
- Window decoration -> Inactive Shadow -> Radius, set it to 0

and reboot.